# submenus are not selected in chrome but it is selected in firefox

Tags: html, css, asp.net

We are working on tabbed menu. Submenus are not working in chrome but are working in firefox.

```
body {
    background:#FFF;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.example {
    width:1000px;
    height:570px;
    border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    font-family:Times New Roman;
    margin:20px auto;
    padding:15px;
}
#nav, #nav ul {
    background-image:url(../images/tr75.png);
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#nav {
    height:41px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-top:5px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
#nav ul {
    left:-9999px;
    position:absolute;
    top:37px;
    width:auto;
}
#nav ul ul {
    left:-9999px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:auto;
}
#nav li {
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
    position:relative;
}
#nav li a {
    background:#AFDCEC;
    color:#000;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    font-size:16px;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:8px 10px;
}
#nav > li > a {
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    -o-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#nav li a.fly {
    padding-right:15px;
}
#nav ul li {
    margin:0;
}
#nav ul li a {
    width:120px;
}
#nav ul li a.fly {
    padding-right:10px;
}
#nav li:hover > a, current {
    background-color:#659EC7;
    color:#000;
}
#nav li.current a {
    background-color:#659EC7;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav li a:focus {
    outline-width:0;
}
#nav li a:active + ul.dd, #nav li a:focus + ul.dd, #nav li ul.dd:hover {
    left:0;
}
#nav ul.dd li a:active + ul, #nav ul.dd li a:focus + ul, #nav ul.dd li ul:hover {
    left:140px;
}
```

I use this code for highlighting menus. When clicking on submenus, submenu is hidden.

Please help me out.

Thanks,
Shree

Comment: show us your HTML part also or jsfiddle is much better.

Comment: Note: CSS code was altered (and commets were removed). See [the revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24115524/revisions) for old version.